# "Value does not fall within the range" windows phone 8

Tags: exception, windows-phone-8

I am creating a project for windows phone, and have made numerous backups over the past month, however when I ran the project this morning I received a Value does not fall within the excepted range error. I have researched this on the internet and all I could find was a few isolatedstorage saving issues which does not apply to me

It happens when I try to navigate to my homepage which is a panorama view, all my server calls are done without issues. And all my backups now also gives this issue. I have no idea where to start looking. the inner stack trace looks something like this:

```
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(IManagedPeerBase obj, DependencyProperty property, Double d)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty property, Double d)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.set_Width(Double value)
at Views.homePanorama.dashboard()
at Views.homePanorama.<OnNavigatedTo>d__7.MoveNext() 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__0(Object state)"
```

Comment: Well, it's hard to tell without the code or the details of the exception, but at least you can see that the problem is in the `Views.homePanorama.dashboard` method, when setting the width of an element, probably with an invalid value (negative?)

Comment: as I was posting this I saw the width of an UI I was setting was set as infinite. Thanx for the comment, you were correct

Answer (score 1):

Width of UI element was coming through as "infinite", just changed that and it worked

Comment: thanks you. I had a similar problem with panorama. Source of the problem   -user component in a ListBoxItem